# Syncing Xbox Wireless Controller w/ Mac

Tags: macos, controllers, xbox

Can anybody please assist me in furthering my attempts to get my Xbox controller properly synced with my Mac Pro? I'm using Snow Leopard and I have downloaded the driver software from tattiebogle.com.

The install went fine, it appeared to sync okay, but when it came to actual gameplay, the controller would not interact with the game and keyboard control still remained.

I've saved, then run a particular script in Terminal, but it could not find the file or directory. That's why I'm trying different avenues of Q & A.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a third party wireless controller for the original Xbox, or an Xbox 360 wireless controller?  If the latter, do you have the wireless gaming receiver?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe the branded wireless gaming receiver is just a disguised bluetooth receiver. It would depends on the software/driver for the controller to make it work with the Mac's current Bluetooth receiver and/or stack. The questioner mentioned that it seemed to sync correctly, though, implying that either A) they have the receiver, B) the software works with the current bluetooth stack or C) is a 3rd party original Xbox controller with a differently handled wireless mechanism.

Comment: The wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_Controller) says that it's proprietary, and specifically not Bluetooth.  I'm inclined to agree.

Comment: Your question started with a good, detailed description, but half-way it derailed and it becomes very difficult to help you. This is very vague: "then run a particular script in Terminal, but it could not find the file or directory" What script? Has it worked before? What is the exact command line, and the full error message? Also, how did you know it appeared to sync okay? Try to be as detailed and as specific as possible (and avoid "everything-in-one-paragraph"). Sorry, I don't have a Mac, I'm just trying to suggest how you can ask for help in a better way.

Answer (score 3):

You **HAVE** to use it wired (USB). The Xbox 360 uses a proprietary wireless protocol, so your computer's Bluetooth antenna will not work with it.

I ran into the same issue with my laptop.

**Update**: I just reinstalled the [Tattieboggle](http://tattiebogle.net/index.php/ProjectRoot/Xbox360Controller/OsxDriver) drivers and tried my wireless over USB. The driver informed me that the wireless controllers *only* operate on wireless, even when plugged in! It said I would need the wireless dongle (an oxymoron if I ever heard one) to use that model of controller with my laptop. I hit the <kbd>guide button</kbd> with it plugged into my laptop and it immediately synced into my Xbox 360.

So yes, you must use USB - either with the dongle or a wired controller. If you do want to buy a wired controller, look at something like the [Razr Onza](http://www.razerzone.com/minisite/onza) (which is well reviewed from what I hear, I have not used one yet; it is also cheaper than an MS controller).